How to edit the nodata value of GeoTIFF using QGIS/GDAL
I've been given a GeoTIFF, and when I open it, it has white areas where there's no data.
In QGIS I've tried looking at the nodata value but it says 'not defined', so after some playing about I found that the white area is 254. This is fine, however there are parts of the GeoTIFF data coloured white (also 254), so if I set the nodata value to that it removes actual data too.
Is there any way to define the white area outside of the aerial imagery with its own nodata value? Via either QGIS or GDAL command

Are the nodata areas located in such way that you could easily digitize a polygon that contains the valid area? Or find the footprint with for example https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_footprint.html by using a large enough min_ring_area? That could be the first step towards adding an alpha band.

Your question is really about whether you can select the white area outside of the aerial imagery separate from the white area inside the imagery. So you will need to provide more details on the imagery, because there's not enough information in the question.

Setting a nodata value will not work as you found. Try the QGIS-GDAL-Raster Analysis-"Near black" tool or the GDAL nearblack commandline utility.  Use the -white parameter to tell GDAL to look for white(ish) rather than black pixels around the edge and either -setalpha or -setmask to output an alpha or mask band.

@TomBrennan I added an image and the gdalinfo output for the raster

You'd be best adding a larger image that shows both the different types of white area. But see user2856's comment
